# How to Filtered objects in json in website

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, api

I have the following api link: http://proxy.tinsoftsv.com/api/changeProxy.php?key=TLXd2WBFWYZGcIUZ0hnn52VFynIlw7yhrmOvPl&location=VN

It will return the following output:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "proxy": "117.1.95.345:12345",
  "location": 1,
  "next_change": "120",
  "timeout": 641
}
```

I am looking for an html code to run on my web. Extracting that result line only takes ip only
Example when running the path: https://hoquangdai.com/ip.html
Then the result will be 117.1.95.345:12345

Please help me!!!

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: I'm not very good, so please help me with a html code :((

Comment: That's javascript, not html. Your question is too vague to be answered. An answer would probably involve the "fetch" function and the extraction of the "proxy" attribute of the returned json.

Comment: So can I run javascript on the web? I just want to run the other link, and then return the result as a proxy

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript has good javascript tutorials for beginners.

Comment: Path: http://proxy.tinsoftsv.com/api/changeProxy.php?key=TLXd2WBFWYZGcIUZ0hnn52VFynIlw7yhrmOvPl&location=VN
Get a list of locations: http: //proxy.tinsoftsv.com/api/getLocations.php
Return value (in json format):
Success :
{"success": true, "proxy": "117.1.95.345:12345", "location": 1, "next_change": "120", "timeout": 641}
-----
I want to get only Proxy: ((

Comment: You have shared a key in your question, you might want to remove it by editing the question. You can read a tutorial on web related to calling an API via javascript for eg. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data